# jQuery.noConflict works but $.conflict does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery with Spring for Web development. As stated above in many places when I use jQuery.noConflict and jQuery instead of '$', it works fine but if I use  $.noConflict and '$', the conflict is not solved. I think the '$' shortcut was added for convenience but if the same is producing conflicts how is it useful?

Example:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "ticket/status/change",
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({"id": id, "status": status}),
  contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
  success: function(response){
  },          
});
```

this works but

```
$.noConflict();
$.ajax({
 url: "ticket/status/change",
 method: "POST",
 data: JSON.stringify({"id": id, "status": status}),
 contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
 success: function(response){
  },          
 });
```

but this won't.

Comment: Are you using a `jquery` version which is below `1.0`?

Comment: `$` might be getting used by some other library you loaded onto the page. So its better to go with `var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); $j.ajax({`

Comment: @DavidR I am using jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: @vijayP why a variable? Why can't I use jQuery directly as in jQuery.ajax  Also jQuery('#tableid').DataTable().ajax.reload(); does not work when I use it as jQuery. I have tried  var table = jQuery('#tableid').dataTable({});  table.api().ajax.reload();